# multiple pages in one html file without fixed nav on each page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Main page would only have several buttons that will show the user designated content.

Those buttons in `#home` is not in header, so buttons will be only shown on `#home` only.

```
<section id="home">
  <a href="#content">content</a>
  <a href="#something">something</a>
  <a href="#someelse">someelse</a>
</section>
<section id="content">
<section id="something">
<section id="someelse">
```

I found `:target` method on css which seems very easy to use and works ok, but `#home` is not displaying.
It seems like it would only work when I have a fixed header outside `section`

```
section {
  display: none;
}
section:target {
  display: block;
}
```

Each section other than `#home` will have back button which will send user to `#home` as well. This was fairly easy on `:target` method because I just used `a href="#"`, and it worked.

What other method would I be able to use ?

Comment: So you want `#home` to show by default when the header is like `www.example.com/html.html` and then show the others when it's specified like `www.example.com/html.html#content`?

Comment: @JackStoller Yes, so `www.example.com` will show `#home` content which would be just buttons for other contents, and after button is clicked, it will be `www.example.com#content` and will show the `#content` content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of any pure CSS ways to do this, but it can easily be done with a little JavaScript to check if the hash is empty, and then show `#home` and hide it when there is a value.

```js
window.onhashchange = checkHash;

checkHash();

function checkHash() {
  var home = document.getElementById('home');

  //Check if the hash is empty
  if (window.location.hash.substring(1) == '') {
    home.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    home.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
.section {
  display: none;
}

.section:target {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="home" class="section">
  <a href="#content">Content</a>
  <a href="#somthingElse">Somthing Else</a>
  <h3>Home</h3>
</div>
<div id="content" class="section">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <h3>Content</h3>
</div>
<div id="somthingElse" class="section">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <h3>Somthing Else</h3>
</div>
```

### Fade

I used `position: absolute` so they will stack on top of each other. `z-index: -1` will keep all the rest of the sections to the clear back to stop pointer events from overlapping. `opacity: 0` was obviously used for the fade.

I changed the JS script to simplify my CSS. Now when you go to `example.com/html.html` you get redirected to `example.com/html.html#home` (without a history change for the back button).

```js
window.onhashchange = checkHash;

checkHash();

function checkHash() {
  //Check if the hash is empty
  if (window.location.hash.substring(1) == '') {
    history.replaceState(undefined, undefined, "#home")
  }
}
```

```css
.section {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  
  opacity: 0;
  
  transition: opacity 0.5s;  
}

.section:target {
  z-index: 1;

  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="home" class="section">
  <a href="#content">Content</a>
  <a href="#somthingElse">Somthing Else</a>
  <h3>Home</h3>
</div>
<div id="content" class="section">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <h3>Content</h3>
</div>
<div id="somthingElse" class="section">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <h3>Somthing Else</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks ! This was exactly I needed. Just wondering, if I were to add some transitions between pages, should I do some extra javascript? or just putting transition under section would work?

Comment: It depends on your transition. `display` cannot be animated. If you want a fade, you'll have to use `opacity` and something else to stop clicks (`display`, `z-index`, etc.) If you want a slide in/out you could use either `margin` or `transform: translate()`. Zoom in/out would be `transform: scale()`. Anything else would probably require a CSS animation. If you want a certain style I could edit my answer with it.

Comment: I was thinking only about bit of fade. I tried with opacity, but it didn't work for me :(. if it doesn't bother you too much, editing answer would be super appreciated.

Comment: @HobbitY Ok, see my edit. I think that is what you're looking for.